One toilet in household clogs consistently
We have a (relatively) new, low-flow toilet in our upstairs bathroom that frequently (pretty much daily) becomes clogged after I defecate. In an effort to try to avoid these daily clogs, I have taken to flushing multiple times during the deed (to create smaller deposits) and use wipes instead of toilet paper. I always dispose of the wipes in the garbage and NEVER have flushed a single wipe down the toilet. I use toilet paper very sparingly the rest of the time and have also never flushed any type of feminine products (or anything else) and there are no children in the household so it's impossible that there is anything else being flushed that might otherwise be causing the problem.
Basically, fresh water flows down the toilet (with each flush) past the fecal deposit rather than the bowl filling and/or overflowing. Most of the time, the part(s) of fecal deposit flushes just beyond site and seems to lodge at the very top of the bowel- just slightly above what is visible. Typically, at first glance, there is no remaining visible evidence of the clog and the problem is evident in major absence in functionality.
Usually, (when it's not clogged) the toilet flushes very quickly and fills instantly. During the clog, upon flushing, the water stalls for a few seconds and then clean/fresh water fills (very very slowly) to the normal waterline. To remedy this, I have tried adding more water to the bowl and repeatedly flushing, which has worked on only a couple instances. The rest of the time, my Dad will "snake" the drain/toilet, which usually takes him a considerable amount of time before the toilet flushes normally again. We also just had out septic tank emptied to rule that out as the problem. My Dad also insists that the toilet itself is not damaged and that he already inspected it for any underlying issues. Also, our other downstairs toilet does not have any issues.
As handy and knowledgeable my Dad may think he is, he is certainly NOT a professional and is reluctant to hire a plumber. It's an extremely frustrating situation for the entire household.
Does anyone have any idea what the problem may be? Can anyone suggest any possible remedies to at least give a try or is hiring a plumber our only option at this point?

use a cup of backing soda and add some vinegar, it will create a foaming/cleaning action, repeat

Is your toilet sewage pipe connected directly to the main stack or does the sewage line have to traverse a horizontal run before it reaches the stack? Is the stack properly vented (not blocked/ restricted)? Toilets work best when the siphoning action is based on the largest immediate drop.

Do you cause problems with other toilets (in the house or elsewhere)? If not, that would indicate an issue with the toilet itself, despite the inspections performed.

Who installed the toilet?  If a non-professional, (or even a professional) the wax ring might be mis-aligned causing a partial blockage that lets liquid through, but provides enough of a restriction that solid matter gets caught up in the partial blockage.  I'd suggest pulling your toilet and checking to make sure the wax ring wasn't mis-aligned.  But you'll want a new wax ring if you do that, since they're pretty much a single use toilet seal.

Worth pointing out: wax rings are very inexpensive. A basic model sells for US $2.00 here in New Jersey, USA. So this is the kind of thing you can afford to check (or encourage your dad to check). Also, there are more expensive models (up to ... $8) that provide better alignment, etc.

When a toilet flushes, it fills the bowl with water to raise the water level in the bowl and the outgoing drain above the "hump" at the back of the toilet (which you can frequently see from the outside). When the water level gets high enough, a siphon effect takes over and "pulls" the water (and "payload") up over the hump and down and out the bottom. To aid this, there is a "water jet" built in to most toilet bowls. It will appear as a small hole, about finger or thumb-sized (depending on your fingers), in the front wall of the bottom of the bowl, underwater most of the time. This hole lets a strong jet of water come down from the flush, pushing the water in the direction of the drain and creating an impulse to kick-start the siphon action.
Maybe it's a misaligned or distorted wax ring
There is typically a gasket installed when the toilet is set over the drain. This gasket is called the "wax ring" even if it isn't wax, or a ring, because a wax ring is still the most common, cheapest, easiest way to create the seal.
Generally, those are the only two "parts" of the toilet. The floor usually holds a "toilet flange", the end of the drain pipe that contains bolt holes for securing the toilet to the drain pipe (and the floor, since the pipe is usually solidly attached to the floor somehow). So: toilet -> wax ring -> flange.
Another answer suggests checking the alignment of the wax ring. Pulling the toilet up will destroy a true wax ring. It's how they work. But wax rings are very cheap, so it's worth doing. (If the wax ring isn't wax, it may be reusable. Even more worth checking in that case.)
Maybe it's a clogged water jet
If the wax ring isn't the problem, my suggestion would be to have a careful look at the water jet. To start with you can probably watch the action while flushing an empty bowl. You should be able to see the jet as the flush occurs, and it should be strong. If you can't see it, put a strip of a few squares of toilet paper down on the side walls, and see if they move during the flush (like putting ribbons near an air vent to show when it is blowing). It is possible that there may be debris blocking  the water jet, weakening or blocking the water jet. The debris may be manufacturing debris, like bits of ceramic, or plumbing debris, like bits of solder, or plastic, or teflon tape that were in a water line when the toilet was first connected. The debris may also be biological, either something that crawled in there, or something that grew in there, or something that "swirled" in there. If you think the jet is clogged, use a soft probe (like a piece of plastic, or a length of copper wire bent to eliminate sharp edges) to gently check if any debris is present.
If there is debris in the jet path, you may or may not be able to get it out. If it is "mechanical" debris, you may be able to remove the bowl, take the toilet someplace soft (like the back yard, if you have a back yard) and turn and shake the bowl until the debris moves back out the hole for the flapper valve. That's a big hole, and if you can get the debris all that way, it will probably come out. But if the debris is the wrong size or shape, it may not be able to pass around the rim of the bowl (if it was the "punchout" of the jet hole, for example) and you may have to try to return/exchange the bowl, or just buy a new one. If the debris is "biological" rather than "mechanical", you might take the bowl outdoors, tilt it to the right angle, and pour some "clog buster" chemicals into the jet path. (note that I am including things like dead mice and snakes, as well as "bilge trout," in the biological debris category).
Family Handyman provides a guide to how a toilet flush works. It shows some of what I'm describing here: https://www.familyhandyman.com/list/how-a-toilet-works/
Maybe it's you
Finally, there is the (remote) possibility that your diet and biology are incompatible with the design of conventional toilets. Maybe your deposits are too rigid, or too large, for standard plumbing to handle. You imply in your post this is not the case, since there are no problems with the downstairs unit. Obviously, choosing to make your deposits downstairs for a week or so would be a good way (and free!) to conduct the experiment. If this turns out to be the explanation, you should consider either changing the amount of fiber in your diet, or investing in a "poop knife".
